# What is the best app for row level permissions in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-permissions

What is the best app for row level permissions in Django?

There are many of them at http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/, but how to choose more promising one?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following that is suitable for any kind of project:

1. **Project popularity between devs**: Check the number of contributors. In GitHub or BitBucket you can get the number of followers/watchers, forks and clones.
2. **Documentation matters**: Avoid the "read the code" dilemma, check if the project is well documented and the compatibility with other packages (like Django).
3. **Maintenance of the project**: Check if there is issues with "open" status for a long time and without response.
4. **Evaluate the open issues of the project**: If the project have open issues, take a look if some of this issues isn't a big problem for your needs.
5. **Check the plugability**: Depending on your needs you may choose a project that is more easily plugable than others.

What I can say more is that I've already used `django-guardian` and it fitted my needs at the time. I think it fits in almost all of these considerations above but give others a try too.